# Would rooting my phone prevent me from using device protection features

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, bootloader

I wanted to unlock my bootl oader so that I can root the device for performance and battery improvement.when I try to turn on OEM unlocking, I am told that the step would deactivate device protection features. I want root and device protection .I dont want to flash custom ROMS or recovery .I just want to root the device and turn the switch back off. Is that possible?

Comment: So if I root my device factory reset protection would still work .?

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Really great ful for the tip . The risk is worth taking.  There's just no custom recovery for my Device and I'm going to make sure that USB debugging is always turned off

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong... See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It appears my comment was incorrect, once you Enable OEM Unlocking in developer options, you have disabled Factory Reset Protection completely.

> If you have Developer options turned on, you can also turn off device
>   protection from your device's Settings app. Tap Developer options and 
>   then OEM Unlocking.
>    - [Source](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en)

And no, once you have unlocked the bootloader (required to root) you can not re-enable this switch, it is greyed out and non-functional, unless you relock the bootloader which cannot be done without have a completely stock image installed, meaning no root, custom recovery, or other modifications to the device.

Comment: Well this is odd. I have unlocked bootloader but "allow oem unlock" isn't grayed out, moreover it can be checked or unchecked (I don't understand this at point where bootloader is unlocked)

Comment: Testing it... Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Tested with a Nexus 5 and Moto G 2015, both on stock Marshmallow, after unlocking (both were unlocked already) the OEM Unlocking switch can be switched on and off, but seems to have no effect on anything and FRP does not function, both devices had Google accounts and after a factory reset I was not required to log back into Google to get to the home screen.

Comment: That's pretty sad . Just one or the other . But after unroot everything should work just fine , I guess .

Comment: All I wanted to really do was to remove some bloatware and convert some few apps into system apps

Comment: @AlainGiresse Modifying modern Android devices is not as simple as it used to be, there are significant implications to unlocking the bootloader and rooting today. Even causing some apps to fail to work do to failure of the SafetyNet API which requires a pure stock phone and will report a fail condition to apps even if you are purely stock and only unlocked the bootloader without modifying anything at all, apps like Netflix, Pokemon Go, Android Pay, and most financial apps will fail to work when a SafetyNet check fails.

Comment: Keep in mind that this security that you loses protect device only from attack performed when someone have physical access to device (but if you connect device to pc with ADB and attacker gain remote access to pc phone will be in trouble but that is big if). So you lose this "protection". Long story short don't let phone in untrusty's people hands and you will be mostly good. Also consider this what acejavelin said. Keep in mind that this can be bypassed (hint: magisk).

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I think the key  point here is that Factory Reset Protection no longer works.