# FRP triggered after hard reset on rooted phone 5.1..Any Explanation?

Tags: rooting, factory-reset

Though I'm a great fan of frp, I'm a greater fan of Rooting. I have an android device running lollipop 5.1 with just so many bloatwares. I rooted the device and got rid of the bloatwares. It was kinda nice that the superuser app was not converted into system app. I Uninstalled it since it was eating up to 54Mb space. I did not lose root privillege. I turned off OEM unlock and was using my device as normal with rooted apps both old and new working fine. It came a time I did a hard reset and frp was triggered. I couldn't setup the device  with any other account except with the last known account. That surprised me because I know rooting turns off frp. Thanks

Comment: @beeshyams I always thought so. No need to even root. Just checking OEM unlocking in developer settings turns off frp

Comment: I've personally tested it on my non rooted 6.0.. Turning OEM on unlocking deactivated frp

Comment: Look at this post https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183000/207780

Comment: +1   for pointing this out. Deleting my comments

Comment: I was stunt. Maybe I will include an external link to a video to see for real how frp works just fine on  a rooted phone